Boost.Asio access violation while destroying io_context with windows::stream_handle and named pipe
I have a service running on Windows which acts as a named pipe server. I am using Boost.Asio to managed the overlapped IO with multiple clients on a single thread while listening for new clients asynchronously. Specifically, I am using the C++20 coroutine support in Asio to write my handler functions.
When the service needs to shutdown, it sets a Windows event object. I spawn 1 coroutine which waits asynchronously on this event, and when received it calls .stop() on the io_context to allow the named pipe server thread to exit gracefully.
The current setup works well; clients can connect, communicate, and disconnect without issue. However, when shutting down I encounter an access violation. This happens even when no clients have connected, and I have narrowed down the issue to the coroutines which wait for a connection.
The stop signal is received in the stop coroutine, .stop() is called on io_context successfully, the .run() call returns and the thread exits and is properly joined. However, when the io_context is destroyed it seems to have trouble cleaning up the service objects (it tries calling a function pointer func_, but that pointer's value is not valid).
It seems I have some lifetime issues, but I'm not sure where they might be. Perhaps there is something I'm not understanding about Asio and how the lifetimes of the coroutines I spawn are managed and how that interacts with .stop().
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/windows/object_handle.hpp>

namespace as = boost::asio;

const char* pipeName = R"(//./pipe/asio-pipe)";

class DuplexPipe
{
public:
    DuplexPipe(as::io_context& ioctx, std::string pipeName)
        :
        stream_{ ioctx }
    {
        const auto pipeHandle = CreateNamedPipeA(
            pipeName.c_str(),
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, // open mode
            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE, // pipe mode
            3,          // max instances
            4096,       // out buffer
            4096,       // in buffer
            0,          // timeout
            nullptr);   // security
        stream_.assign(pipeHandle);
    }
    as::awaitable<void> Accept()
    {
        as::windows::object_handle connEvt{ co_await as::this_coro::executor,
            CreateEventA(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr) };
        OVERLAPPED over{ .hEvent = connEvt.native_handle() };
        ConnectNamedPipe(stream_.native_handle(), &over);
        if (const auto error = GetLastError(); error == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            // not yet connected, await on connection event
            co_await connEvt.async_wait(as::use_awaitable);
        }
        else if (error == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED) {
            // connected even before we could await event
        }
        else {
            // some error has occurred during connection
            std::cout << "Failed to connect" << std::endl;
            std::terminate();
        }
    }
private:
    as::windows::stream_handle stream_;
};

class PipeServer
{
public:
    PipeServer()
        :
        stopEvent_{ ioctx_, CreateEventA(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr) }
    {
        thread_ = std::jthread{ [this] {
            as::co_spawn(ioctx_, [this]() -> as::awaitable<void> {
                co_await stopEvent_.async_wait(as::use_awaitable);
                ioctx_.stop();
            }, as::detached);
            as::co_spawn(ioctx_, Accept_(), as::detached);
            ioctx_.run();
        } };
    }
    void SignalStop()
    {
        SetEvent(stopEvent_.native_handle());
    }
private:
    as::awaitable<void> Accept_()
    {
        DuplexPipe pipe{ ioctx_, pipeName };
        co_await pipe.Accept();
        // at this point in the actual app we would spawn another Accept_ coro and then
        // proceed to communicate with the connected client
    }
    as::io_context ioctx_;
    as::windows::object_handle stopEvent_;
    std::jthread thread_;
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    PipeServer srv;
    while (!_kbhit());
    srv.SignalStop();

    return 0;
}

Above is a minimal reproduction of the issue.

Can you create a reproducer that isn't windows specific? Perhaps replacing named pipes with regular TCP connections? Without more looking it seems that given jthread you might use std::stop_token/``std::stop_callback` and given C++20 I think there are far simpler approaches using cancellation a slot - look at any of https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20awaitable_operators&searchOn=3 for inspiration

I will try to repro with TCP when time permits, but named pipes / Windows is essential to my use case and I fear the error might be intrinsic to my use of object_handle here. Mostly I'm just looking to confirm/refute my usage of .stop() in this case.

You can still learn a lot. I don't see how it should matter, and you would still learn 99% of the cause by demonstrating that it is specific to this particular IO object.

I have not been able to reproduce this with platform agnostic constructs (specifically TCP async_accept). Digging deeper into above repro, I note that it does not fail if I merely wait on event without initiating the overlapped op. It also succeeds if I initiate overlapped op, but the pipe handle is not assigned to the asio stream object. It seems that having a pending overlapped operation on the stream during ioctx destruction is the trigger, even though the op was initiated outside of asio. Perhaps on closing the handle, gets a winapi error and tries to inform nonexistent completion handler

The problem appears to have stemmed from starting an overlapped io operation outside of Asio. I can only speculate on the exact mechanism of the failure, but the solution is straightforward.

Create the named pipe and store the handle in a temporary handle container instead of immediately assigning to the Asio stream_handle object. Only assign to the stream_handle after the connect operation has completed successfully.

Call GetOverlappedResult to properly conclude the overlapped operation before transferring pipe ownership to Asio.



Good thinking. And thanks for sharing the experience
